# Fluent NHibernate - Mapeamento chave composta um para muitos

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Estou com um problema para mapear uma entidade pelo *Fluent NHibernate*.

Tenho uma relação 1-N com as duas tabelas no banco tendo chaves compostas.

Quando tento listar minha entidade *Usuario* volta um erro, mas isso acontece apenas quando crio a relação com a entidade *AcessoDepartamento*

**UsuarioMap**

```
public class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Email, "Usuario")
            .KeyReference(x => x.Empresa, "CodEmp")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.CodigoFilial, "Filial");

        Map(x => x.Nome, "Nome");
        Map(x => x.AcessoTodosDepartamentos, "AllDeptos");
        Map(x => x.AcessoTodosPedidos, "allPed");
        Map(x => x.Email, "email");
        Map(x => x.NivelUsuario, "UsrTipo")
            .CustomType<NivelUser>();
        Table("Usuario");

        References<Empresa>(x => x.Empresa, "CodEmp");
        References<CentroCusto>(x => x.CentroCusto, "CCusto");
        References<Departamento>(x => x.Departamento)
            .Column("CodDep");

        HasMany<AcessoDepartamento>(x => x.AcessoDepartamentos)
            .KeyColumn("AcessoDep");
    }
}
```

**AcessoDepartamentoMap**

```
public class AcessoDepartamentoMap : ClassMap<AcessoDepartamento>
{
    public AcessoDepartamentoMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.AcessoDep, "AcessoDep")
            .KeyReference(x => x.Departamento, "CodDep");

        Map(x => x.CodigoFilial, "Filial");
        Table("AcessoDep");

        References<Departamento>(x => x.Departamento)
            .Column("CodDep");
        References<Empresa>(x => x.Empresa)
            .Column("CodEmp");
    }
}
```

Já tentei de tudo que já vi pelas pesquisas que fiz e nada até agora, continua voltando esse erro:

> Foreign key (FK44A92FD8F30CB372:AcessoDep [AcessoDep])) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (Usuario [Usuario,
>   CodEmp, Filial])

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Seu `AcessoDepartamento` também tem uma coluna chamada `Filial`? O detalhe é que o NHibernate está tentando adicionar um FOREIGN KEY ao `Usuario`, mas precisa referenciar as três colunas que compõe o usuario.

Comment: Eu tentei referenciar as três colunas como o erro dizia, nesse caso o erro parou de aparecer, mas não puxou a referencia do `AcessoDepartamento`. Dessas três colunas o `AcessoDepartamento` só não tem o `Usuario`, as outras duas (`Filial` e `CodEmp`) ele tem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463163/1245766) no Stack Overflow em Inglês, mas na minha experiência uma coisa assim ajuda e resolve mesmo:

```cs
HasMany<AcessoDepartamento>(x => x.AcessoDepartamentos)
  .KeyColumns.Add("AcessoDep", "CodDep").Cascade.All();
```